# Sensor contact with kinematic vs dynamic fixtures

Tags: qml, box2d

I'm trying to detect a moving object by adding a sensor to a stationary object. `box1` is stationary and has a large circular sensor, and `box2` is kinematic and is moved by setting its linear velocity.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Box2D 2.0 as Box2D

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Box2D.World {
        id: physicsWorld
        gravity: Qt.point(0, 0)
    }

    Item {
        id: box1
        x: window.width / 2 - width / 2
        y: window.height / 2 - height / 2
        width: 32
        height: 32

        property int sensorRadius: 128

        Box2D.Body {
            id: boxBody
            target: box1

            fixtures: [
                Box2D.Box {
                    width: box1.width
                    height: box1.height
                },
                Box2D.Circle {
                    x: box1.width / 2 - box1.sensorRadius
                    y: box1.height / 2 - box1.sensorRadius
                    objectName: boxBody.objectName + "CircleSensor"
                    radius: box1.sensorRadius
                    sensor: true

                    onBeginContact: touchIndicator.border.color = "red"
                    onEndContact: touchIndicator.border.color = "transparent"
                }
            ]
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: touchIndicator
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: box1.sensorRadius * 2
            height: box1.sensorRadius * 2
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "transparent"
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: box2
        x: 100
        y: 160
        width: 32
        height: 32
        focus: true

        Keys.onSpacePressed: box2Body.linearVelocity = Qt.point(3, 0)

        Box2D.Body {
            id: box2Body
            world: physicsWorld
            target: box2
            bodyType: Box2D.Body.Kinematic

            Box2D.Box {
                width: box2.width
                height: box2.height
            }
        }
    }

    Box2D.DebugDraw {
        id: debugDraw
        world: physicsWorld
        anchors.fill: parent
        opacity: 0.75
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: wrong]

The sensor doesn't detect the moving object.

If I make the moving object dynamic:

```
bodyType: Box2D.Body.Dynamic
```

it then detects it:

[image: right]

What is the correct way to do this?

Please keep in mind that:

1. I want to keep the movement simple because I suck at accurate movement via forces (hence my current approach with `linearVelocity` and wanting to use `Kinematic`).
2. I don't want/need anything to actually collide with and bounce off anything else, I just need sensors and ray casting.

Comment: Kinematic body has no mass so it doesn't involve in collision detection. Box2D just not able to calculate bouncing and all about that. Kinematic bodies are mostly intended to a static structures.

Comment: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/bodies says that kinematic bodies can move, and the example on [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/05/11/understanding-box2d-kinematic-bodies/) page shows them colliding with dynamic objects. Are you sure they can't be used in the way I'm trying to use them?

Comment: Yes, kinematic bodies are not affected by force. Box2D implements Newton physics and so bodies with infinite mass (like kinematic one) cannot be involved in collision detection. If you target is avoiding collision (just act like a sensor) you can play with `Fixture.categories` and `Fixture.collidesWith` like in one of examples. I don't remember which of them.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if we're on the same page here. As I said, I don't want them to be affected at all, I just want them to move through a scene and be detectable by another sensor somewhere else in the scene. Judging from the two links I provided, it seems that the engine is indeed able to detect when a kinematic body collides with a dynamic one, and so I'm confused as to why it couldn't do the same with a sensor.

Comment: Yes, collision could be detected between Dynamic and another body. I mean one of bodies should be Dynamic. In your case they are Kinematic and Static.

Comment: A-ha! For some reason I assumed that it defaulted to a dynamic body if you didn't specify it! :D Setting `bodyType: Box2D.Body.Dynamic` on the body that contains the sensor fixes it, thanks! It's gonna be a bit weird because the body that contains the sensor never moves, so it feels like either way I have to make one of the bodies dynamic - but if that's how it has to be for it to work, so be it. :)

Comment: Do you wanna answer this so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kinematic body has infinite mass so it cannot be involved in collision detection. To detect collision one of bodies must be `Dynamic`. By default `bodyType` in `qml-box2d` plugin is `Static`. So your scene contains 2 bodies - `Kinematic` and `Static` and sensor doesn't detect contacts. Changing `boxBody.bodyType` to `Body.Dynamic` solves the issue.